# Best approach for django-celery-twisted powered GPS tracking system

Tags: python, django, celery, twisted

I'm currently working on developing a GPS tracking system and my configuration is the following:

- React for the web display.
- Django with django-rest-framework for the api to query the database.
- Twisted to listen to TCP port and receive GPS data.
- Celery to save the data from twisted to DB asynchronously.
- Redis to transfer data from Twisted to Celery.

I have always work with python so, as you can see, that is my primary choise.
This approach is kinda working but I'm affraid that maybe it will not going to be scalable. Already got 5 GPS but only one is reporting, I'm trying to find out the reason, but that not the question.
Does somebody know a better approach using python? It's this a common pattern? I'm worried about the "Twisted - Redis - Celery" part.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is for specific questions about programming. Complex system architecture problem and recommendations are off-topic and too broad.

Comment: No problem with deleting it but where can I go to ask this kind of question? @KlausD.